# How to make react native app save the language when changed from the app with i18next?

Tags: react-native, localization, i18next, asyncstorage, react-i18next

I'm using **i18next** in react native to use multi languages in the app :
the user can change the language from the app by clicking on a button
in this button I make an action to set the language in **AsyncStorage** ,
in i18next init file I want to use the value of the AsyncStorage, but its not changing it because AsyncStorage it need async and await so it take long time to change the value ,
this is the code :

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import English from '../Translation/Languages/English.json';
import Spanish from '../Translation/Languages/Spanish.json';
import Arabic from '../Translation/Languages/Arabic.json';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

let language = null;

const changeLanguage = async () => {
try {
    const Lang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Language');
    if (Lang !== null) {
        language = Lang;
    }
}
catch (error) {
    console.log("Error ", error)
}
};

changeLanguage();

i18n
.use(initReactI18next)
.init({
    lng: language,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    resources: {
        en: English,
        es: Spanish,
        ar: Arabic
    }
});

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this [medium-post](https://hend-elsahli-freelance.medium.com/how-to-dynamically-change-app-language-and-app-direction-in-react-native-bfccf567c40c) for a working sample...

**Github Repo**
https://github.com/hend-elsahli/ReactNativeLocalization

use `languageDetector`

```
i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .init(...)
```

- 

```
const languageDetector = {
  init: Function.prototype,
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true, // flags below detection to be async
  detect: async callback => {
    const selectedLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Language');
    /** ... */
    callback(selectedLanguage);
  },
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};
```

Comment: I'm gonna post a medium blog post very soon with a working example ... which doesn't fit a SO-answer

Comment: @SharifAl-Hayek a working sample-app is now available in the mentioned medium post...

Comment: Is there a way to add a default language?

Comment: @OliverD yes... use `.init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli can u check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161101/how-to-set-the-default-language-in-i18next-react-native), please?