# i18next change language inside async causes memory leak

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks, use-effect, use-state, i18next

I allow the user to select a language within the app and I store it locally. When they come back in the app, I try using AsyncStorage to fetch the language but when I call

```
i18n.changeLanguage(currentLanguage)
```

it causes a memory leakage. here is my code

```html
const [language, setLanguage] = useState('') 
    const {t} = useTranslation();    
    const fetchLanguage =  async () =>{
        try{
            const currentLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language')
            if (currentLanguage === null ){
            }
            else{
                setLanguage (currentLanguage)
                i18n.changeLanguage(currentLanguage)
            }
        }catch (e){
            console.log(e)
        }
       
    }
    useEffect (()=>{
        fetchLanguage()
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use `i18n.changeLanguage(currentLanguage)` inside the useEffect, use the language detector when you initialize i18next. you can then have a fault back language.The credit to this answer goes to Hend El-Sahli's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227252/how-to-make-react-native-app-save-the-language-when-changed-from-the-app-with-i1)

```html
const initialLanguage = 'en'

const languageDetector = {
  init: Function.prototype,
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: async callback =>{
    const storeLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("language")
    const selectedLanguage = storeLanguage || initialLanguage
    callback(selectedLanguage)
  },
  cacheUserLanguage: () =>{}
}


i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .use(languageDetector)
  .init({
    resources: resources,
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    fallbackLng:'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
});

export default i18n;
```